# MYSQL Comma Delimited list, possible to add and remove values?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a comma delimited list that im storing in a varchar field in a mysql table.

Is it possible to add and remove values from the list directly using sql queries?  Or do I have to take the data out of the table, manipulate in PHP and replace it back into mysql?

Comment: Now you understand why normalization is important.

Comment: What are you doing - are you trying to write your own little database... in SQL?

Comment: can you be more specific about how you are trying to manipulate this string?  are you sure you need to be storing a string into this table?  it's really bad practice unless you are doing something like pre-calculating info that you can't do in real time for users.

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454610/mysql-remove-the-specific-word-in-comma-seperated-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do it in InnoDB and MyIsam engines in mysql. Might be in other engines (check CSV engine).
You can do it in a stored procedure, but, not recommended.
What you should do to solve such an issue is to refactor your code and normalize your DB =>
original table

```
T1: id | data                    | some_other_data
     1 |  gg,jj,ss,ee,tt,hh      |   abanibi
```

To become:

```
T1: id | some_other_data
     1 |   abanibi

T2: id   |  t1_id    |   data_piece
     1   |    1      |      gg 
     2   |    1      |      jj 
     3   |    1      |      ss 
     4   |    1      |      ee
     5   |    1      |      tt
     6   |    1      |      hh
```

and if data_piece is a constant value in the system which is reused a lot, you need to add there a lookup table too.

I know it looks more work, but then it will save you issues like you have now, which take much more time to solve.