# Having multiple rows in one row using for xml path

Tags: mysql, xml

I have the following query but i get this error: Syntax error, unexpected XML_SYM, expecting UPDATE_SYM

```
select ','+ description from users 
join access_rights 
on users.id_users=access_rights.users_id_users
join doors 
on doors.id_doors=access_rights.doors_id_doors 
for xml path('');
```

Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FOR XML` is [supported in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx), but I'm not aware if the same also supported in MySQL. Looks like it is not, according to what happened when you run the query containing `FOR XML` in MySQL.

Search for solution that is specifically proven to be working with the same DBMS. In SQL Server, your query will return `description`s as comma-separated values. To return comma-separated values in MySQL, use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) instead of `FOR XML` :

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(description) from users 
.....
```

- [MySQL Results as comma separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662207/mysql-results-as-comma-separated-list)
- [MySQL column data returned as comma delimited list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987154/mysql-column-data-returned-as-comma-delimited-list)
- [comma separated string of selected values in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558443/comma-separated-string-of-selected-values-in-mysql)

Comment: Thank you very much, it was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support XML queries like this - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847674/xml-output-from-mysql) for alternatives. [It seems](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2410) they do consider it as something they might implement in the future.

Right now, MySQL is complaining about the word `XML` which it doesn't know - the word `FOR` is only used in the combination [`FOR UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Comment: Thank you for your question but how can I do this, to have multiple rows in  one row result. I search on the internet and I found this FOR XML and STUFF function.

Comment: Do you have a working example for a query like this without a JOIN?

Comment: I have a query working example with join because this query result is what I want, but to multiple rows in only one row. This is the query that works

Comment: select name,description 
from users 
join access_rights 
on users.id_users=access_rights.users_id_users
join doors 
on doors.id_doors=access_rights.doors_id_doors
order by name;

Comment: But that's not an `FOR XML` query, is it?

Comment: No it isn't because how you said mysql doesn't support xml. That my problem, what to do instead of this, because the query that I've posted in this question works in SQL-Server

Comment: http://davidduffett.net/post/5334646215/get-a-comma-separated-list-of-values-in-sql-with

Comment: Then, please have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847674/xml-output-from-mysql) which I already mentioned in my answer.

Comment: this is the site where I got the information, it's exactly what I want to do, but in MYSQL

Comment: Please keep in mind that while MySQL and SQL Server both understand SQL, they both have different 'dialects'. `FOR XML` is simply not in MySQL's dialect.